# React fragment shorthand failing to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

The project in question is using React-16.2.0 which has the capability to use Fragments and the Fragment shorthand.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

While the full-length syntax works fine...

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';

class TestingFragment extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <span>This is a fragment of text </span>
                <div>Another part of the fragment</div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
};

export default TestingFragment
```

The shorthand fails to compile and I am at a loss as to why this is. Fore example...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestingFragment extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <span>This is a fragment of text </span>
                <div>Another part of the fragment</div>
            </>
        )
    }
};

export default TestingFragment
```

Which fails to compile as follows...

```
Failed to compile
./src/testingFragments.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (6:4)

  4 |   render() {
  5 |       return (
> 6 |           <>
    |            ^
  7 |               <span>This is a fragment of text </span>
  8 |               <div>Another part of the fragment</div>
  9 |           </>
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Is there something here I am missing about the Fragment shorthand syntax?

Comment: Have you configured babel as described in documentation?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think this is a reason:

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax

**[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5fc9.jpg)**

create-react-apps currently use **Babel 6.26.0**
for full support React.Fragment is needed **Babel v7.0.0-beta.31** and above

======================= EDIT

It's working now with create-react-app v2
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html

Comment: Tried with `babel` standalone `7.1.0` in Code and still it doesn't work..

Comment: is there a CDN version of babel-standalone 7.* ?

Comment: Yes @Petruza - CDN link for latest babel-standalone is: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 13):

You can use the *poor man's* fragment shorthand as a quick fix: `[` `,` `]`

```
render(){
  return [
    <div key="f">foo</div>,
    <div key="b">bar</div>
  ]
}
```

as array of nodes is a valid jsx element. You need to add a `key` prop to each of them manually though as [Anarno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316365/react-fragment-shorthand-failing-to-compile/60269454?noredirect=1#comment123920184_60269454) pointed out.

Comment: Just add a key to each element!

Answer (score 6):

Fragment syntax is only supported by Babel v7.0.0-beta.31 & above.