# ReactJS: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token "

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very much new to React. The following is my first script.

But I am getting the following error.

```
Failed to compile

./src/components/Layout/index.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (12:5)

  10 | const Layout = (props) => {
  11 |   return(
> 12 |     <>
     |      ^
  13 | 
  14 |    <Header />
  15 |    {props.children}
```

here is my Layout component code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';


/**
* @author
* @function Layout
**/

const Layout = (props) => {
  return(
    <>

   <Header />
   {props.children}
   </>
   )

 }

export default Layout;
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What version [of Babel are you running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316365/react-fragment-shorthand-failing-to-compile)?

Comment: Provide more information like your babel configuration and how you are compelling

Comment: And is your project setup to handle JSX in .js files? Or does it need to be .jsx

Comment: Have you tried adding a space after the word `return`? Or deleting the newline after the opening parenthesis?

Comment: please try this one and tell us about the feedback. remove your empty tags <></> and replace it with <React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>

Comment: @novonimo thank you so much , its works after adding <React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>  , but can you explain me why this error appears with <> </> ?

Comment: @Andy 
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.15.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5"
  }

Comment: @Prototype It means you’re using a React version before `<></>` was supported.

Comment: If this is causing you trouble use `React.Fragment` whilst sorting out any babel stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try using `Fragment` which came from the `React` library.

it provides an empty tag like `<> </>` but older versions of the JSX Babel plugin didn’t understand it.

as mentioned in the question's comments, it's an issue with your `babel` plugin version.

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';

const Layout = (props) => {
  return(
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      {props.children}
   </Fragment>
   )

 }

export default Layout;
```