# Issues with JSX syntax during React's TicTacToe tutorial

Tags: reactjs, tic-tac-toe

While attempting React's TicTacToe tutorial (https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) on my local development environment, I ran into this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7VfG.png) after copy-pasting the following from the tutorial's spec.

```
export default function Square() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="board-row">
        <button className="square">1</button>
        <button className="square">2</button>
        <button className="square">3</button>
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <button className="square">4</button>
        <button className="square">5</button>
        <button className="square">6</button>
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <button className="square">7</button>
        <button className="square">8</button>
        <button className="square">9</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I was expecting to reach the next step of the tutorial, as it required 0 brainpower to copy-paste the code. I have no real experience with HTML, CSS, or JSX syntax, so I have no idea what this issue could be. I know those are important prerequisites but I intend to learn as I go.

If you have any idea as to what may be causing this error, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console after npm start? Are you in the browser page auto started by npm start?

Comment: What are you using in terms of Babel / Vite? Could you try adding `import React from 'react';` to the top of the file?

Comment: @Spikatrix I'm not sure, do you know how I can check?

Comment: @JohnWilliams no console errors. Just the one I've displayed. And yes, this is the auto-generated npm server.

Comment: @BenStephens I added that line and nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: @GarrettMoore Open your `package.json` file. You should see something like `"react": "17.0.2"` in it. Here it's using React 17. Edit: Just noticed from another comment that you're using react 18. This should work in react 18 just fine. Perhaps you can try deleting your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install` after that to fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to wrap .board-row divs with React Fragments. You can check about Fragments [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

You can also use <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>

Comment: The `<>...</>` is a shorthand for `<React.Fragment>`. The code posted is already wrapped in that so this can't be the solution.

Comment: @Taxel I think it could be if they have old React / Babel versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316365/react-fragment-shorthand-failing-to-compile

Comment: How do you check your react version @BenStephens ? My NodeJS version is 20.0.0.

Comment: @GarrettMoore Do you have a package.json file in the root of your project folder? There should be an entry under "dependencies" for React, probably also Babel or Vite.

Comment: @BenStephens it looks like I have React Version 18.0.0

Comment: ```{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "main": "/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.0"
  },
  "name": "ljg0t8",
  "description": null,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}```

Comment: @GarrettMoore It's probably worth adding your package.json to the question.